# SceneKit euler angles not working on iOS 8

Tags: ios, scenekit

In the scene builder, I add a cylinder node to my scene with a euler angle of (0,90,0).  This looks great on my scene.  Now when I go to run it,  the euler angle gets ignored on iOS 8, but works on iOS 9.  I have tried looking on here for a work around using euler angles, but I could not find one, so I am asking if anybody has found a work around to this problem. I have tried removing the node and adding it back into the scene, but that did not work.  Like I said, this is done through scene builder, so there is no code to show for this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer/work around is that for iOS you have to manually assign the euler angles in code, it seems that pulling the node from the scn file will not carry over the euler angles assigned to it, and you can't even reassign the current value (let x = node.euler.x; node.euler.x = x) because it will pull a 0.

Also,  the scene builder takes in degrees, the code takes in radians.

Code Behind:

```
let node = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("nodename")
node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(M_PI_2),0,0)
```

Comment: Cool bug! I filed rdar://24634001. I started with the default game template and, in the scene editor, gave the ship a pitch, roll, and yaw of 45 degrees each. On both iOS 8.4 and iOS 9.2, all of orientation, eulerAngles, and rotation came out all 0 when I queried them programmatically. And on iOS 8.4, the ship wasn't rotated at all.

Comment: even on iOS 9 it came to 0?

Comment: Yes. It renders correctly on iOS 9, but the retrieved values are wrong. Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378583/scnaction-rotatebyangle-rotation-is-inverted-in-el-capitan-or-metal?

Comment: That just makes it even more weird, but good to know it was not just me haha.